data frame join by column containing array and then group by
i have two dataframes:
df1 = c1, c2, c3
       1,  2, [1,2,3,4]
       8,  9, [10,11]


   
   
df2 = c4, c5, c6
       3,  4, [1,2]
       5,  6  [2,3]
   
   
   

i want to  join df1 and df2 by  arrays intersection (c1 intresect c6) and then group by
c1 and c2 where r1 contains a list of dataframe rows of df2
result = c1, c2, r1,
         1   2,  [row(3,4), row(5,6)]
     

how do i achive that effiecntly
i have tried using merge, group by

I'm assuming [row(3,4), row(5,6)] means the c4/c5 values from df2

IIUC, you can explode, merge, keep only one occurrence of the overlap with drop_duplicates, then agg+groupby.agg:
out = (df1.explode('c3')
          .merge(df2.explode('c6').reset_index(), left_on='c3', right_on='c6')
          .drop_duplicates(['c1', 'c2', 'index'])
          .set_index(['c1', 'c2'])[['c4', 'c5']].agg(list).agg(list, axis=1)
          .groupby(['c1', 'c2']).agg(list)
          .reset_index(name='r1')
      )

Same logic but combining all columns except those used for merging (here c3/c6):
key_left = 'c3'
key_right = 'c6'

cols_left = list(df1.columns.difference([key_left]))
cols_right = list(df2.columns.difference([key_right]))

out = (df1.explode(key_left)
          .merge(df2.explode(key_right).reset_index(), left_on=key_left, right_on=key_right)
          .drop_duplicates(cols_left+['index'])
          .set_index(cols_left)[cols_right].agg(list).agg(list, axis=1)
          .groupby(cols_left).agg(list)
          .reset_index(name='r1')
      )

Output:
   c1  c2                r1
0   1   2  [[3, 4], [5, 6]]

Reproducible inputs:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1,8], 'c2': [2,9], 'c3': [[1,2,3,4],[10,11]]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c4': [3,5], 'c5': [4,6], 'c6': [[1,2],[2,3]]})

